# When I use a service a form on my controller is not known to the scope of the service

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code factory:

```
angular.module('common')
    .factory('_g',
    ['$http', '$q', '$resource', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '_o', '_u',
    function ($http, $q, $resource, $rootScope, $timeout, _o, _u) {

        var _init = function ($scope) {
            $scope.modalReset = function () {
                _modalReset($scope); // << No modalForm appears on this scope
            };
        };
        var _modalReset = function ($scope) {
            $scope.modalForm.$setPristine();
        };

        return {
           init: _init,
           modalReset: _modalReset
        }
```

In my controller I initialize the service like this at the start of the code:

```
   _g.init($scope);
```

On my page I have a form:

```
   <form class="form" name="modalForm">
      <button data-ng-click="modalReset()">
          Reset
      </button>
```

From what I learned this form will be added to the scope dynamically and appear as $scope.modalForm

When my form calls `$scope.modalReset` it executes BUT there is no modalForm on the $scope when I check it with the debugger.

Can someone explain why this is. What it seems like is that the service is being passed the 
scope at an early stage before the modalForm has been added. Is this the case and is there a 
way that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **its not good practice to use `$scope` into factory/service**. Services are Singletons.

This logic you can write in directive or controller.

Anyways, from your example I don't see you pass somehow `$scope` as argument to both methods. I would change factory to:

```
angular.module('common')
    .factory('_g',
    ['$http', '$q', '$resource', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '_o', '_u',
    function ($http, $q, $resource, $rootScope, $timeout, _o, _u) {

        var _init = function ($scope) {
            $scope.modalReset = function () {
                _modalReset($scope); // << No modalForm appears on this scope
            };
        };
        var _modalReset = function ($scope) {
            $scope.modalForm.$setPristine();
        };

       return {
        init: function ($scope) {                
           return _init($scope) ;
        },
        _modalReset: function ($scope) {                
           return _init($scope) ;
        }
     }
    }]);
```

Comment: You mention I should write the logic in my directive or controller but in my case I did this as there are many controllers that share the same logic. Is there another better way I could do this. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @SamanthaJ sure. I you have duplicate code in controllers that uses `$scope`, create parent controller.

Comment: Thanks for the advide Maxim.